# MultiSelectListPreference setEntries doesn't show up

Tags: java, android, listpreference, android-multiselectlistpreference

I am trying to build an android app and I need a `MultiSelectListPreference` option in the settings menu. I have created a `PreferenceActivity` to handle this and I created a `preferences.xml` file as well, but I need to be able to load the list elements dynamically in the program. I know that I need to use the `setEntries` and `setEntryValues` methods to do this, but when I use these methods no exceptions are thrown and the title and summary of the `MultiSelectListPreferenc` show up but no elements appear.

I have verified that the arrays I am using to populate `entries` and `entryValues` are not empty by printing them out, as well as by printing out the result of `getEntries()` and `getEntryValues()` after having `set` them and both these show the entry list to be populated; however no elements show up.

My `preferences.xml` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <MultiSelectListPreference
        android:key="markedApps"
        android:title="Targeted Apps"
        android:summary="Select apps to conditionally disable" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

My `AppSettings.java` code:

```
public class AppSettings extends PreferenceActivity {
    public static MultiSelectListPreference blocked;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        blocked = new MultiSelectListPreference(this);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new PrefFrag()).commit();
    }
    public static class PrefFrag extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
            MultiSelectListPreference blocked = (MultiSelectListPreference)findPreference("markedApps");
            if (blocked == null)
                Log.e("NullPointerException", "Blocked is null");
            AppSelector.populateAppList();
            CharSequence[] appNames = new CharSequence[AppSelector.Data.appNames.size()];
            CharSequence[] allApps = new CharSequence[AppSelector.Data.allApps.size()];
            int i = 0;
            for (String appName : AppSelector.Data.appNames)
                appNames[i++] = (CharSequence) appName;
            i = 0;
            for (String app : AppSelector.Data.allApps)
                allApps[i++] = (CharSequence) app;
            blocked.setEntries(appNames);
            blocked.setEntryValues(allApps);

        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help you provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow so I feel extremely stupid now. Turns out my problem was that I expected the list to show up under the title and summary whereas you actually have to click on the title and summary to make the list pop up.